# "undefined reference to `__stat_time64'" when cross-compiling rust project on musl 1.2.0

Tags: rust, arm, cross-compiling, musl

I'm trying to cross-compile a rust project for `arm-linux-musleabihf` and am hitting a linker error when using `musl-cross-make`. The rust project has a dependency on `libgit2` and this is the dependency that seems to be causing the problem.

Using:

- the latest rust (1.43.1 via `rustup`)
- the `arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf` target
- the latest `musl-cross-make` with `TARGET=arm-linux-musleabihf`
- pointing `TARGET_CC_linux_arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf` and `CARGO_TARGET_ARM_UNKNOWN_LINUX_MUSLEABIHF_LINKER` at `/opt/musl-cross-make/output/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc`

I get an error when building:

```
error: linking with `/opt/musl-cross-make/output/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
...
  = note: /opt/musl-cross-make/output/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-musleabihf/9.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-musleabihf/bin/ld: /tmp/rustcvSvGAJ/liblibgit2_sys-e56c2f9bd024a0a9.rlib(odb.o): in function `git_odb__add_default_backends':
          odb.c:(.text.git_odb__add_default_backends+0x24): undefined reference to `__stat_time64'
          /opt/musl-cross-make/output/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-musleabihf/9.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-musleabihf/bin/ld: /tmp/rustcvSvGAJ/liblibgit2_sys-e56c2f9bd024a0a9.rlib(config.o): in function `git_config_add_file_ondisk':
          config.c:(.text.git_config_add_file_ondisk+0x34): undefined reference to `__stat_time64'
          /opt/musl-cross-make/output/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-musleabihf/9.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-musleabihf/bin/ld: /tmp/rustcvSvGAJ/liblibgit2_sys-e56c2f9bd024a0a9.rlib(config_file.o): in function `config_file_read':
          config_file.c:(.text.config_file_read+0x48): undefined reference to `__stat_time64'
...etc...
```

It looks like the linker is having difficulty resolving the musl-specific `time64` symbols, and it's not clear why.

This works fine if:

- I use the `x86_64-linux-musl` target on both rust and `musl-cross-make`
- I build `musl-cross-make` with `MUSL_VER=1.1.24`

I also wrote a little C program that uses both `time` and `stat`, and this builds on musl 1.2.0 on the cross compiler without any issue.

What's going on here? What's special about `libgit2` which means that it can't find the right `__time64` symbols?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the MUSL libc that ships with Rust versions up to and including 1.44 is MUSL libc 1.1.X based, not 1.2.0.

When Rust builds libgit2 is also needs to build libgit2-sys, which is C code.  When building libgit2-sys it uses the MUSL libc version that you've built and installed yourself with musl-cross-make.  This is 1.2.0 by default, which has reworked `time_t 32/64` bit support, having a dependency on `__stat_time64` and various other similarly named methods (such as `__time64`).

However, when Rust is linking your final application it is using the version of MUSL libc shipped with Rust for the x86_64-linux-musl target, which doesn't include that new time_t support, and doesn't have `__stat_time64`, `__time64`, etc.  So the link fails.

Right now you have 2 options:

- Use musl-cross-make to build 1.1.24 of MUSL lib.  I'm not 100% what version is included with Rust 1.44.  It may be 1.1.22, although from my own testing I found 1.1.24 works just fine (as have you).
- Build your own version of Rust and/or the target liblibc.rlib with your own version of MUSL libc.  I've never managed to successfully achieve this myself, although [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24777) might be a good place to start if you want to try this.

The general issue of using libc shipped with Rust, instead of a locally provided version, is being worked on, e.g. [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72274).

Comment: Thanks for this - it makes sense. I might see if I can build my own rust with musl 1.2.0, and also follow along the linked issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to go with option 1:

  - install musl-cross-make
  - download the source for MUSL lib of the correct version
  - compile it

But then how do I get Rust (or cargo?) to use that version?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the instructions listed in https://github.com/richfelker/libcompat_time32:

> Add `-Wl,--whole-archive -lcompat_time32 -Wl,--no-whole-archive` to the link command line. Special hacks (like prepending `-Wl,` to `-lcompat_time32`) may be needed if libtool is intercepting and mangling the command line.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make much of a difference. Building `libcompat_time32.a` and trying to add it in with `-Clink-arg=-L/path/to/libcompat_time -Clink-arg=-lcompat_time32` still gives the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying out https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross : it sets up the environment for cross-compilation in docker and seamlessly works, even for the case highlighted here.

AFAICT, they recompile musl with the correct version.